# Azure SignalR negotiate fails

Tags: azure, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I have angular project hosted on www.allbaskets.com 
An Api app in asp.net core 3.1 on messenger.allbaskets.com  with SignalR Hub called messengerhub registered as Messenger. 
The hub is using Azure SignalR.

I've adde CORS https://www.allbaskets.com , https://allbaskets.com to the APi
and  https://www.allbaskets.com , https://allbaskets.com , messenger.allbaskets.com  to CORS in Azure SignalR
The APi and angular app is hosted on Azure app service.
On connecting www.allbaskets.on the browser  i constantly see a negotiate failed with the url as 
https://messenger.allbaskets.com/Messenger/negotiate

Comment: What CORS do your have on Azure Portal for the SignalR?

Comment: https://www.allbaskets.com , https://allbaskets.com

Comment: Remove the CORS from the portal. You need the CORS to be configured only on your app.

Comment: that didnt help either... if the negotiate fails is token getting passed?